how to debug this biquad IIR filter that uses polyphase decimation?
I am trying to debug an implementation of a polyphase decimated biquad IIR filter.  The difference equation for this filter is
$y_{(\downarrow L)}[i] = y[iL] = \displaystyle\sum^{L-1}_{l=0} \left( \displaystyle\sum_{m=0} b_{ml(\downarrow L)} x_{l(\downarrow L)}[i-m] - \displaystyle\sum_{n=1} a_{nl(\downarrow L)} y_{l(\downarrow L)}[i-n]\right)$
The filter software calculates sets of coefficients of $b_0, b_1$ and $a_1, a_2$ for each of $L$ biquads using pairs of complex poles / zeros with matching complex conjugate or simply real poles and zeros.  The calculation always has an even number of poles and may or may not have an even number of zeros.
My question is why only $b_0, b_1$?  I would expect $b_2$ for the following reason:
To generate the coefficients the partial fraction decomposition is performed in the z-plane.  To keep things simple consider one of the biquads and a pair of complex poles / zeros:
$H(z) = {K \prod_{o} (z - \gamma_{o}) \over \prod_{p} (z - \lambda_{p})} = K {(z - \gamma)(z - \overline\gamma) \over (z - \lambda)(z - \overline\lambda)} = K{z^2 - 2\Re(\gamma) z + \lvert \gamma \rvert \over z^2 - 2\Re(\lambda) z + \lvert \lambda \rvert} = K{1 - 2\Re(\gamma) z^{-1} + \lvert \gamma \rvert z^{-2} \over 1 - 2\Re(\lambda) z^{-1} + \lvert \lambda \rvert z^{-2}} = {b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2} \over 1 + a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2}} = \frac{Y(z)}{X(z)}$
Now the z-transform of the input signal $$X(z) = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=-\infty}x[i]z^{-i}$$ and the output signal $Y(z) = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=-\infty}y[i]z^{-i}$ can be used to generate the required difference equation by inspection of parts with the same power of $z^{-i}$
$\begin{aligned} \sum^\infty_{i=-\infty}y[i]z^{-i} &= \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=-\infty}x[i]z^{-i} (b_0 + b_1 z^{-1} + b_2 z^{-2}) - \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{i=-\infty}y[i]z^{-i}(a_1 z^{-1} + a_2 z^{-2})\\
y[i] &= b_0 x[i] + b_1 x[i-1] + b_2 x[i-2] - a_1 y[i-1] - a_2 y[i-2]\\
\end{aligned}$
The implementation calculates the partial fractions in the z-plane so starting with the poles and zeros (again I simplify by showing only 2 of the possible 2$L$ poles / zeros) it uses the Heaviside cover up method
$$\begin{aligned} H(z) &= K{(z - \gamma)(z - \overline\gamma)\cdots \over (z - \lambda)(z - \overline\lambda)\cdots} \\
&= K\left(1 + {A \over (z - \lambda)} + {B \over (z - \overline \lambda)} + \cdots\right) \\
&= K\left(1 + {A (z - \overline \lambda) + B (z - \lambda) \over (z - \lambda)(z - \overline \lambda)} + \cdots\right) \\
&= K\left(1 + {0z^2 + (A + B)z - (B\overline \lambda + A\lambda) \over z^2 - 2\Re(\lambda)z + \lvert\lambda \rvert^2} + \cdots\right)  \\
&= K\left(1 + {0 + b_1z^{-1} + b_2z^{-2}\over 1 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}} + \cdots\right)  \\
\end{aligned}$$
So that is what I would expect, but the actual software uses
$b_0 = (A + B), b_1 = -(B\overline \lambda + A\lambda)$
and in the case where there are an even number of complex zeros the filter adds an additional biquad with the constant term derived from the "1" in the Heaviside cover up method.  In the case where there is an odd number of zeros and an even number of poles the "1" term in the Heavside cover up method is not needed.
Is there some magic about polyphase decimation that I have missed where the following is valid:
$H(z) = {b_0 z + b_1 \over z^2 + a_1 z + a_2} = {b_0 + b_1z^{-1}\over 1 + a_1z^{-1} + a_2z^{-2}}$

All this is interesting.  I need to look at it to understand what you're trying to do.  Usually I am more comfortable about polyphase decimation applied to the output (or input) of FIR filters.  Then there is no real difference between what happens without decimation vs. what happens with decimation.  But for IIR it's more complicated.
